# Increment input values in array by 1? Result is [1,1,1..]

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a beginner programmer in Java and my professor give us optional assignments to practice coding. For this one I have to:

Write a method that gets as an input an int array and returns a second array where all the elements in the first array were increased with 1.

So for example the input is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] --> Output: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

This is what I have so far:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    public class AddOne {
        public static void main(String [] args){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            int [] a = new int[5];
            System.out.println("Enter numbers for array: ");
            for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
                a[i] = input.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.print("Output: " + Arrays.toString(add(a)));
        }

        public static int [] add(int [] array1){
            array1 = new int [array1.length];
            int [] array2 = new int[array1.length];

            for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
                array2[i] = array1[i] + 1;
            }

            return array2;
        }
    }
```

Right now my output is [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] so the input values aren't being stored properly, any hints? Also should I be declaring another array in the main method since in add() I have array1 and array2? I tried messing around with it before, but things just got more messed up and I had some weird output.
This is only my first or second time posting here, sorry if I formatted anything wrong.

Comment: Why do you do this: `array1 = new int [array1.length];`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     public static int [] add(int [] array1){
        array1 = new int [array1.length];
        int [] array2 = new int[array1.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
            array2[i] = array1[i] + 1;
        }

        return array2;
    }
```

In the first line of code in this function, you made the parameter (array1) a NEW array. All int arrays have a default value of 0. When you iterate through the array, you're adding 1 to each element. As a result, you'll return an array filled with 1's.

Should be:

```
public static int[] increment(int []array){
    int[] toRet = new int[array.length];
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    toRet[i] = array[i]+1;
}
    return toRet;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] incrementArray(int[] array) {
  int[] incrementedArray = new int[array.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    incrementedArray[i] = array[i] + 1;
  }
  return incrementedArray;
}
```